# Broadcasting over Wi-Fi Direct

Tags: java, android, broadcast, socketexception, wifi-direct

I'm looking at the possibility to broadcast over a Wi-Fi Direct connection between multiple Android devices. I've created a simple message broadcasting application to test whether or not it works, but so far I haven't been able to broadcast a message. When I try to send the packet I get a **SocketException** (Network is unreachable):

```
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180): sendto failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:496)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:465)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:182)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:307)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at com.example.android.wifidirect.UdpBroadcaster.sendMessage(UdpBroadcaster.java:59)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at com.example.android.wifidirect.UdpBroadcaster.run(UdpBroadcaster.java:44)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:463)
03-20 13:23:00.148: E/UdpBroadcaster(4180):     ... 4 more
```

This is the essence of my code:

```
InetAddress broadcastAddress = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
int port = 8888;

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
socket.connect(broadcastAddress, port);

String message = "Hello";
byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();

DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
        buffer, buffer.length, broadcastAddress, port);

try {
    socket.send(packet); // <----- Causes a SocketException
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095414/is-multicasting-possible-with-wi-fi-direct) suggests that broadcasting over Wi-Fi Direct should be possible.

Does anyone know whether broadcasting over Wi-Fi Direct on **Android** devices actually works? If it should work, what am I doing wrong?

I'm starting to think the devices does not know where to route the broadcast packets. In my case it needs to work without having to root the device and manually add a route for broadcast packets.

---

**Update**

After using the `getBroadcastAddress()` function suggested by *Romain Hippeau* the SocketException disappeared and it seems like the broadcasting is working as intended. However, I'm having problems receiving the broadcast on the second device.

I'm using the following code to receive the broadcast:

```
DatagramSocket socket = null;
try {
    socket = new DatagramSocket(8888);
    socket.setBroadcast(true); // Not needed?
    socket.setSoTimeout(200);

    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    while (!mStopping) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        try {
            socket.receive(packet);

            if (packet.getData().length > 0) {
                String receivedString = new String(packet.getData());

                Log.i(TAG, "Received string: " + receivedString);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedIOException e) { /* Ignore */ }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    if (socket != null)
        socket.close();
}
```

I have also tried to add a wildcard address to the `DatagramSocket` by adding `InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0")` as argument, but no luck.

Suggestions?

Comment: BTW: Look at this article: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Shamelessly stolen from https://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP**

Try getting you network connection this way:

```
InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
    WifiManager wifi = mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    // handle null somehow

    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
    return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}
```

Then try sending a packet this way:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
    getBroadcastAddress(), PORT);
socket.send(packet);

// If you want to listen for a response ...
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

Edit: From same page to read try this ...

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("dk.aboaya.pingpong");
lock.acquire();
serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(19876);
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(15000); //15 sec wait for the client to connect
byte[] data = new byte[UDPBatPositionUpdater.secretWord.length()]; 
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
serverSocket.receive(packet);
lock.release();
String s = new String(packet.getData());
System.out.println(s);
```

Remember, that you need the following permission for it to work:
**<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>**

Comment: The SocketException disappeared after using that function to get the broadcast address and the broadcasting seems to work, but I'm having problems receiving the broadcast on the second device. I initialize a `DatagramSocket` in the same manner on the receive device. I have also tried to use a wildcard address on the receiving `DatagramSocket` by adding `InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0")` as argument. No luck.

Comment: @user2190832 added some more detail to my answer to read UDP.

Comment: Code works great, thanks! Some details regarding devices:

I build my own libraries for handling this communication based on this code. I'm currently using port 8888. My Nexus 5 can send and receive. My Moto G can only send packages (and receive their own, but not form other devices). I recently tried in a Samsung Galaxy S2 and can send and receive packages.

Somehow Motorola is blocking the incoming broadcasts. I tried in two different Moto G, one rotted with specific firewall policies and one stock, but no luck.

Comment: this doesn't work for me neither, only group owner able to receive broadcast packet, but client cannot, both devices are Samsung (c5 & c7).