# Please suggest whether Android WiFi Direct supports Multicast Socket communication

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, multicastsocket

Using WiFi Direct in Android is it possible to establish a MulticastSocket communication? 
I tried a lot for multicast socket communication between S3 and Note2 devices but no success.

Is WiFi Direct supports MultiCast commnication in Android. If yes please please share sample code. I will be very greatful to you

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10517551/382892

> Based on the technical specs, the Group Owner shall act as a DHCP server and
>   provide an IP address to the connected clients (which should act as a
>   DHCP client). Each device can easily know its own IP and the GO's IP,
>   so it should be possible to do a broadcast using the address
>   255.255.255.255.
>
> Regarding a proper multicast, I am not sure, I guess it depends on the
>   capabilities of the DHCP server created.